# How do you mock a function inside a for loop

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I am using python's mock and patch library. I have a function that needs to be unit tested.

I want to unit test `func` & mock/patch `get_me_info` function that iterates over the keys `A, B, C` and for each key returns a different dataframe output.

So `get_me_info(pro_id='A')` returns data frame as

```
   src_id    date_info
0  A_src1    <date-string1>
1  A_src2    <date-string2>
```

So `get_me_info(pro_id='B')` returns data frame as

```
   src_id    date_info
0  B_src1    <date-string1>
1  B_src2    <date-string2>
```

Below func() needs to be tested:

```
def func():  
   result = []     
   for pro_id in [p.upper() for p in INFO]: # pro_id corresponds to here A/B/C keys in INFO

       df = cat_svc.get_me_info(pro_id=pro_id) # this call needs to be mocked

       for _, row in df.iterrows():
           # do some work that populates result & needs to be unit tested


   return result


INFO = {
        "A": {
            "s_key1": "a_val1",
            "s_key2": 11},
        "B": {
            "s_key1": "a_val1",
            "s_key2": 31},
        "C": {
            "s_key1": "b_val1",
            "s_key2": 23},
}
```

How should I have different mock dataframes returned by `get_me_info` to test `func` and this dict `INFO`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new function of for loop and mocking that functionality. So I tested `bar` function instead of `func` now and was able to mock `df = cat_svc.get_me_info(pro_id=pro_id)`.

```
# These functions are inside MyClass

    def func():  
       result = []     
       for pro_id in [p.upper() for p in INFO]: # pro_id corresponds to here A/B/C keys in INFO

           result.append(self.bar(pro_id))


       return result


    def bar(pro_id):
       res = []
       cat_svc.get_me_info(pro_id=pro_id) # this call needs to be mocked

           for _, row in df.iterrows():
               # do some work that populates res & needs to be unit tested
               #res.append(row)


        return res
```

And here is the test:

```
   test_info = [
        {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': u'val2'},
     ]

    @mock.patch('a.b.get_me_info')
    @mock.patch('c.d.init')
    def test_bar(self, init_mock, me_mock_info):
        my_class = MyClass()
        me_mock_info.return_value = pd.DataFrame(test_info)
        result = my_class.bar(pro_id='test_id')
        self.assertIsNotNone(result)
        me_mock_info.assert_called_with(pro_id='test_id')
```